# How to change JSON object before send ExtJS

Tags: javascript, wcf, json, extjs

I everyone i have a JSON Array that is construct like this

```
 for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) 
            {                
                var record = myDataStore.getAt(i);

                if (record.dirty){                    
                   submitRecords[currentIndex] = record.data;
                   //alert(submitRecords[currentIndex].ConversionDate);
                   currentIndex++;
                }
            }
```

The problem is that inside the record.data there are dates and when i tried to send it to my WCF service of course give me an error because it does not have the properly date format, an i was wondering is there someway to change specific properties of my JSON object with or without Ext

Comment: Are you in control of the contents of `record.data`? How are the date values in there generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

record.data.field = value;

Answer (score 0):

sorry i was doing it wrong

```
record.data.ConversionDate=Ext.util.getMicrosoftAjaxDate(record.data.ConversionDate);
```

PD. Ext.util.getMicrosoftAjaxDate is a generic own Function to parse dates